# Can't resolve Error: member function 'getDV' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Vertex', but function is not marked const

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to write an overloaded < operator and I keep getting this error

1. error: member function 'getDV' not viable: 'this' argument has
     type 'const Vertex', but function is not marked const

I've gone back and tried to change both my variable dv and the function getDV() to const
but that didn't help either. I feel like I'm just cycling between 2 different errors. Any help would be great, y'all! Thanks!

```
friend bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2);

bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2)
{
  return v1.getDV() > v2.getDV();
}


///HERE'S MY VERTEX CLASS//////
#include "Vertex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const bool myFunction(Vertex & x, Vertex & y);
void shortestPath(vector<Vertex> & v);


///overload the less than operator in order to use the stl sort for vector
///print out the path for each vertex

int main()
{

    /////READ ALL THE STUFF INTO THE GRAPH////
    ifstream file;
    file.open("graph.txt");
    cout << "Opening file..." << endl;
    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "System failed to open file.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;
    }

    int numVertices;
    int numEdges;
    int num;
    int adjacentVertex;
    int weight;

    file >> numVertices;
    vector<Vertex> vertices(numVertices + 1);

    for(int i=1;i<=numVertices;i++)
    {   
        file >> numEdges;
        Vertex newVertex;
        //Using the i counter variable in the outer for loop to identify
        //the what vertex what are currently looking at in order to read in the correct adjacent vertex and weight
        newVertex.setVertexNum(i);

        for(int j=1;j<numEdges;j++)
        {
            file >> adjacentVertex;
            file >> weight;
            newVertex.setAdjacentVertex(adjacentVertex, weight);
        }
        vertices.push_back(newVertex);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<numVertices+1;i++)
    {
        cout<< "V" << i <<":  ";
        for(int j=0;j<vertices[i].getAdjacentVertices().size();j++)
        {
            cout << "V" << vertices[i].getAdjacentVertices()[j].getAdjVertex() << " " << vertices[i].getAdjacentVertices()[j].getWeight() << endl;
        }
    }





    //CALL THE SHORTEST PATH FUNCTION ON THE GRAPH/////



}

/*
const bool myFunction(const Vertex & x, const Vertex & y)
{
    return (x.getDV() >= y.getDV());
}
*/

bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2)
{
    return v1.getDV() > v2.getDV();
}

void shortestPath(vector<Vertex> & v)
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].getDV()<< endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, y'all, I mean to label that as my main

Comment: You need `const` between the parameter list and the start of the body (or if is just a declaration, after the parameter list).

Comment: So, between the "<" and the first parenthesis?

Comment: I mean `getDV()` should be declared like `return_value getDV() const ...`

Comment: `shortestPath` should take a `const` reference , since it doesn't modify the vector.